# Sorting files by number of words

Tags: c#, winforms

Basically i need to sort a file by the number of words so in example if the file contains the following text:

1. This is Fourth
2. This is the second line
3. This is the Third
4. This is the first line of words

I would need it to be sorted to this:

1. This is the first line of words
2. This is the second line
3. This is the third
4. this is fourth

So sort by the number of words on a line.

Comment: Good, So what did you try and where are you stuck?

Comment: Sounds like homework...

Answer (score 3):

If words are separated by white-spaces:

```
var sortedLines = File.ReadLines(path).OrderByDescending(line => line.Split().Length);
```

If you don't want to count consecutive or leading/trailing spaces:

```
var sortedLines = File.ReadLines(path)
.OrderByDescending(line => line.Trim().Split(new char[]{},StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Length);
```

Using `Split()` or `Split(new char[],...)` will split by [white-space characters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.char.iswhitespace(v=vs.110).aspx) which includes new-line-, space- or tab characters.

if you want to add others you have to build the `char[]` or `string[]` manually.

Comment: @fubo: OP hasn't explained what is valid or invalid. He can use the Split overloads to handle edge cases. But i have now shown another version to give a hint.

Comment: My first idea was to count the appearence of space characters for sorting - after I notices this issue I discarded my answer :D `.OrderByDescending(line => line.Count(x => x = ' '))`

Answer (score 0):

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"E:\1.txt");
var sotedLines = lines.OrderByDescending(line => line.Split().Length)
.ToList();
```

Comment: And why parallelize this? There is no benefit at all.

Comment: @PatrickHofman i thought that would get executed using thread pool

Comment: So? What benefit does it have to read those lines on multiple threads?

Comment: if there are many lines, certainly it would be beneficial

Comment: No, it is not... `OrderByDescending` can't be parallellized. So you are reading all lines, then parallelize the one-by-one input of `OrderByDescending`.

Comment: yeah right! got it :)

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: @Adam the code itself self explanatory, what do you want me to describe?

Answer (score 0):

```
    static void Main(String[] args) {

        var lines = File.ReadAllLines(args[0]);
        lines.OrderByDescending(s => s.Split().Count());
        File.WriteAllLines(args[0], lines);
    }
```

Comment: That answer was given 9 minutes ago already.

Comment: @PatrickHofman: not really, this doesnt work